# Compile 32bit and 64bit projects at the same time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation

i use Visual Studio 2010 and have a problem. I have a solution with 15 projects and more, some of them should only compiled as 64bit, other only as 32 bit. 
For example

MySolution

- MyClient
- MyClientFramework
- MyServer
- MyServerFramework
- MyUtils ...

MyClient references MyClientFramework and MyUtils and should compile as 32bit. 
MyServer references MyServerFramework and MyUtils and should compile as 64bit.
Actual I only can compile the 64bit projects, then change the configuration and compile the 32bit projects. I want to compile and debug the whole solution at the same time. How the *.csproj files have to configured?

Comment: Does MyUtils *have* to be built as 32 or 64-bit? Can't it be built as AnyCPU?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you want to compile MyUtils in 32bit when building MyClient and 64bit when building MyServer and do all that in one go?

Comment: @jon: First I thought AnyCPU was the solution for my problem. But on some website I read following ->If you platform target is "Any CPU" then your project will normally be targeted at whatever platform is available, i.e. x64 on a 64 bit OS. So MyClient (32bit) (with a AnyCPU compiled MyUtils DLL) will not work on 64bit machine!

Comment: Ok the solutions was AnyCPU! But on i found a lot of wrong information in the internet about AnyCPU (seeing my comment above)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Batch Build` entry under `Build` button, you can use that. It will offer to select the needed projects and configurations. The downside is that `Batch Build` does not allow adding new entries, so in case if you need a 32bit and 64bit instance of the same project at once you may need to call `msbuild` from the command line directly and specify the project and needed targets (see reference here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx).